# Having a list inside recursive function's impact on memory/resources

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, memory, resources

I am new to Python and I plan on having a list inside a recursive function such as

```
def myRecursion(a):

    A = [0,1,2]    

    #Rest of code here
    myRecursion(a-1)
```

My question is will having `A` inside the recursion **create many instances of it** and eat up my resources? I should also note that the contents of the list is **always the same**.

Comment: are you modifying the values in A in any way?

Comment: @Primusa no the contents in A will always be the same

Comment: Couldn't you just make A a global that your functions access

Comment: @Primusa I've been taught to avoid global variables whenever I can, how bad is it really to use global variables in programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer with some sample timings: Yes, creating a list inside of a recursive function will have an impact on performance, as opposed to creating it outside a recursive function and passing it in.

```
In [1]: def recursion1(n):
   ...:     A = [1,2,3]
   ...:     return n if n == 0 else recursion1(n-1)
   ...:

In [2]: %timeit recursion1(1000)
232 µs ± 7.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [3]: def recursion2(n, A):
   ...:     return n if n == 0 else recursion2(n-1, A)
   ...:

In [4]: A = [1,2,3]

In [5]: %timeit recursion2(1000, A)
163 µs ± 681 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

> My question is will having A inside the recursion create many instances of it

We can use [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) to check the identity of an object:

```
In [6]: def recursion1(n):
   ...:     A = [1,2,3]
   ...:     print(id(A))
   ...:     return n if n == 0 else recursion1(n-1)
   ...:

In [7]: recursion1(3)
129035280
134141552
129297184
134141472
Out[7]: 0

In [8]: def recursion2(n, A):
   ...:     print(id(A))
   ...:     return n if n == 0 else recursion2(n-1, A)
   ...:

In [9]: recursion2(3, A)
133702400
133702400
133702400
133702400
Out[9]: 0
```